# Guidelines for Salesforce Database (Objects) design

Tags: custom-object, data, database

What are the best practices for Salesforce Database structure (Object structures)? . It is very difficult to query data from a highly normalized structure. As in we cannot follow the RDBMS (Oralce Db, My SQL) design standards due to query limitations. Any suggestions on this?